# Lua, WOW and "..."

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

Getting my feet wet in Lua and writing some simple addons for *World of Warcraft*. Primarily looking through other addons, inspecting the code, etc. I'm seeing one thing that has me confused. I know that `...` is a way to pass variable number of parameters to a function, but I'm seeing it used at the beginning of a `.lua` file:

```
local parent, ns = ...
```

Again, this is the first line in the source. The only references I see to the file is in the `.xml` file, included as a script

```xml
<Ui>
    <Script file="unitframes\options\ouf.lua"/>
</Ui>
```

I'm curious where the values being passed in are coming from...

ANSWER:

As the answer below indicates, WoW is passing the arguments to the script. Aparently, WoW passes the following arguments to a script:

1. Name of the AddOn as a String (actually the folder name)
2. A table unique to the AddOn (often used as the AddOn's namespace). This table is shared w/ all the lua files in the addon and provides an "AddOn" only scoped context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 8 of "Programming in Lua"

> In the main body of a script, the expression "..." results in the arguments to the script.

So `a` and `ns` should receive the first two arguments passed in by WOW.

Comment: Makes sense. Guess I should try to figure out what arguments WOW is passing in.

Comment: If I understand correctly (and its a big "if"), in my snippet above, "parent" should receive the 1st argument, and "ns" should get the 2nd argument. Is this correct? (going off of pg 40 in "programming in Lua"

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what it is.